# Two UITableView's in one View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I've found many questions and answers on this issue but I still dont seem to be able to fix my issue. 
I've got this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    if(tableView == self.moduleTableView){
        UITableViewCell *cell = [_moduleTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableIDCell"];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"TableIDCell"];
        }
```

Thats all fine and works for the `moduleTableView`  and I have code to fill the individual cells.
However, I later have an `if(tableView == theOtherTableview)` and the code is never executed, (have used break points to check). Because of this the second tableview never loads and fills. 
I've done for the same if statements in the `numberOfRows` method and I declare:

```
  self.tblEvents.delegate = self;
  self.tblEvents.dataSource = self;
  self.otherTblEvents.delegate = self;
  self.otherTblEvents.dataSource = self;
```

and it still doesn't work, am I missing anything? I think I've linked the implementation correctly to the storyboard, I just can't get it to reload the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method while `(tableView == OtherTableView)`

Thanks

Comment: check the theOtherTableview's delegate is set....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section` method returns zero value (empty array count), Cell for Row Method will be called only if `numberOfRowsInSection` method returns non zero value.

`numberOfRowsInSection` should return a non zero value

Comment: just to clarify `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` should not return an array, just a number. generally that will be the `count` property of some array though.

Comment: Why does the world have so many idiots like me and so few good people like you. Thanks, this solved my issue!

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue as you. 
I found that the cleanest solution is to make 2 datasource classes. That way there is alot less code in your view controller. 
Basically something like this

```
   DatasourceTblEvents *ds1 = [DatasourceTblEvents new];
   DatasourceotherTblEvents *ds2 = [DatasourceotherTblEvents new];

   self.tblEvents.dataSource = ds1;
   self.otherTblEvents.dataSource = ds2;
```

This dramatically reduces the amount of `if` statements within the datasource protocol methods. And this way you can just implement the datasource methods in each datasource class like you would with one table view.

Hope this helps.